# How to determine if Octave package is compatible with Octave version? Errors when installing packages on Octave v7.1.0

Tags: package, octave

I recently upgraded Octave to v.7.1.0 and am having trouble installing various packages, such as signal and tablicious.  I can't tell if it is due to a compatibility issue or if I'm doing something else wrong.  How can one tell if a package is compatible with the Octave version?
When i try to install signal, I get

```
error: the following dependencies were unsatisfied:
signal needs control >= 2.4
```

Then, when I try to install control, it gives a ton of warnings mostly indicating this warning:

```
warning: load path C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\octave\api-v57\packages\signal-1.4.1: No such file or directory`
```

Again, not sure if it is something I'm doing wrong or if the packages are incompatible with this version of Octave. I can't decipher the errors/warnings.

Thank you.

Comment: do you by any chance have packages installed from a previous octave installation in your package folder? might be worth cleaning those up and installing again from scratch

Comment: ok...I do have them from v6.4....let me try that...thank you